# Enterprise Redhat RHEL Server default/built-in Applications?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm gonna buy a RHEL Server but before i do it, i very much need to be confirmed about some built-in Applications/Softwares which will come along with, inside.

Does it come along with following Applications?

- Apache
- MySQL
- PHP

.. and the versions?

Also if possible, can i know the complete list of default built-in Applications/Softwares inside which will be coming along with?

Comment: Other than bash and coreutils, and a few other very basic things, you need to decide what's installed at install time or through a package manager. Get the corresponding version of centos to the version of RHEL server you're buying, get a VM and check what's there ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every RHEL comes with that software, as well as their free derivates: [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/) and [ScientificLinux](https://www.scientificlinux.org/).

I have a server running ScientificLinux 6.3 with the following versions of the software you are interested on:

- Apache (httpd): 2.2.15
- MySQL (mysql-server): 5.1.66
- PHP (php): 5.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Also, remember that for zero upfront cost, you can install Centos which is Redhat w/o the proprietary RH packages.  You could explore that release and see if you provides what you want.

Also, for a list such as this, I'd really contact RedHat directly.